# Setting the scope of a Singleton in Google Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a Contact class, a ContactFactory class that creates contacts and a singleton ContactList that stores all Contacts created in my program. I just introduced Google Guice to inject a couple of dependencies into the ContactFactory and was thinking I would also inject the ContactList with the @Provides and @Singleton annotations but it's not working the way I was hoping for.

I've taken most tests out but the below two capture the issue:

```
public class ContactTest {
    ContactFactory factory;
    ContactList contacts;
    Injector injector;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        contacts = ContactList.getInstance();
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new ContactFactoryModule());
        factory = injector.getInstance(ContactFactory.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBasicContact(){
        ContactInfo info = new ContactInfo();
        info.add(PhoneNumber.create("07778777888"));
        info.add(EmailAddress.create("test@example.com"));
        String primaryKey = "2000000";
        DatabaseFields fields = new SimpleDatabaseFields("Mr Joe Bloggs", info, primaryKey);

        Contact contact = factory.create(fields);

        assertEquals("Mr Joe Bloggs", contact.getDatabaseFields().getName());
        assertEquals("2000000", contact.getDatabaseFields().getPrimaryKey());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSecondContactAddedToChildContactsOnMerge(){
        ContactInfo info = new ContactInfo();
        info.add(PhoneNumber.create("07778777888"));
        info.add(EmailAddress.create("test@example.com"));
        String primaryKey = "2000000";
        DatabaseFields fields1 = new SimpleDatabaseFields("Mr Joe Bloggs", info, primaryKey);
        ContactInfo info2 = new ContactInfo();
        info2.add(EmailAddress.create("test@example.com"));
        info2.add(PhoneNumber.create("07778888777"));
        DatabaseFields fields2 = new SimpleDatabaseFields("Mr J R Bloggs", info2, "2000002");

        Contact contact1 = factory.create(fields1);
        Contact contact2 = factory.create(fields2);

        assertEquals(1, contact1.getChildContacts().size());
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown(){
        contacts.clear();
    }
}
```

With the ContactList injected using Guice, I was expecting to be able to comment out the ContactList field, the initialisation of it in setUp() and the clearing of it in tearDown(), but the second test fails when I do that.

I have an understanding of why. Given the ContactList is persisting between tests, and assuming the tests are executed in top-to-bottom order (which is the case in my IDE), the Contact in the first test remains in the ContactList and, when contact1 and contact2 are created and checked to see if they are duplicates, they are both being found to be duplicates of the first contact and added to its childContacts list.

Please could someone give me some guidance? I'm thinking I've either (a) missed the point of Guice and the answer is to initialise/clear the ContactList each time like I was doing before or (b) I've missed a different part of Guice that's intended for this. I can provide more code if anyone needs it but I think I've captured the essence of the problem and would imagine it's a simple answer to someone in the know.

Comment: For each test, you will have to use a new injector. If you're sharing the same injector across all tests, they will all use the same singleton. Making a new injector per test will allow you to use new singletons in each one.

Comment: I've got the instantiation of the injector in the @BeforeEach setUp() method though, so I'm not sure this is it - I've just debugged through the whole test class and the ContactList was at2424 each time but the Injector was at2260, then at2468, then at2476, etc.

Comment: could you post your unit test code? We would be able to understand better if we at least had a look at that file, without it we can only guess what is going wrong

Comment: @ellis I've added a test class that captures the issue

Comment: I made [a sample repository here](https://github.com/elliscode/guice-example) to demonstrate the desired behavior is possible, i am still having trouble understanding the nature of your issue, I think I would need to see the entire codebase to understand if there was any problems with your annotations or module. Let me know if this helps at all

Comment: Thanks for helping me, based on what you've got I'm missing a binding in my ContactFactoryModule but I can't quite apply what you've done to what I've done. It might help you to see [my repo](https://github.com/andersgoddard/SingleCustomerTool/tree/main/src/main/java) - I need to sort the structure out but the FactoryModule is in the Utilities package and the rest is in the Contact package. Sorry, I've made a bit of a mess of this post!

Comment: I [forked your repository here](https://github.com/elliscode/SingleCustomerTool/tree/ellis-fixes), specifically the branch ellis-fixes, the changes I made are: 1. fix the pom.xml file, the dependencies for guice were in the wrong block, and the second dependency was invalid, and junit was not present 2. added src/test/java directory and moved tests there 3. commented out the failing checks in your unit tests ---- get back to me if this helps at all, i'm still not completely sure of your issue. I'm thinking maybe you were using junit annotations without using junit to run your tests?